# sql insert query with select query using pythonn and streamlit

Tags: python, sql-server, select, sql-insert

i have an sql `insert query` that take values from user input and also insert the **ID** from another table as foreign key. for this is write the below query but it seems not working.

Status_type table

```
CREATE TABLE status_type (
ID int(5) NOT NULL,
status varchar(50) NOT NULL
);
```

info table

```
CREATE TABLE info (
ID int(11) NOT NULL,
name varchar(50), NULL
nickname varchar(50), NULL
mother_name varchar(50), NULL
birthdate  date, NULL
status_type int <==this must be the foreign key for the status_type table
create_date date
);
```

for the user he has a dropdownlist that retrieve the value from the **status_type table**  in order to select the value that he want to insert into the new record in the **info table**
where as the info table take **int Type** because i want to store the **ID** of the status_type and **not the value**

## code:

```
    query = '''
            INSERT INTO info (ID,name,nickname,mother_name,birthdate,t1.status_type,created_date)
            VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
                      
            select t2.ID
            from info as t1
            INNER JOIN status_type as t2
            ON t2.ID = t1.status_type
            '''    
            args = (ID,name,nickname,mother_name,db,status_type,current_date)
                       
   cursor = con.cursor()
   cursor.execute(query,args)
   con.commit()
   st.success('Record added Successfully')
```

the **status_type** field take an INT type (the ID of the value from another table ).
So when the user insert  it insert the value.

What i need is to convert this **value** into its corresponding **ID** and store the **ID**

Comment: What number should be sent for the ID field in your code?
The output of the select can be several records

Comment: In the select query i am trying to convert the string   that he intered in the  **status_type variable** into its corresponding ID

Comment: You have to extract the status_type ID separately and send it as a parameter to the query.
This code will not give you correct output. The written selection shows the number of records in the output info table.

Comment: So let say the value of the variable `status_type = employee` and in the status_type table the emplyee ID = 1
How to perform what you are suggesting?

Comment: I didn't understand the structure of two tables. Is the **status_type** table filled after the **info** table?
You can write the select in value.`INSERT INTO (...) VALUES ((SELECT TOP 1 ...) ,? ,?)`
If the structure of the two tables with the data is clear, I can help you better.

Comment: I will edit the question an add the 2 tables

Answer (score 0):

When creating a record, you can do one of these ways.

- Receive as input from the user
- Specify a default value for the field

  INSERT INTO (...) VALUES (? ,? ,1 ,? ,?)
- Use a select in the INSERT

  INSERT INTO (...) VALUES (? ,? ,(SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM status_type ODER BY ID) ,? ,?)

When INSERT data, you can only enter the names of the destination table fields. t1.status_type is wrong in the following line

```
INSERT INTO info (ID,name,nickname,mother_name,birthdate,t1.status_type,created_date)
```

Comment: based on your answer i tried the third point as this :
`query = '''
            INSERT INTO info (ID,status_type,created_date)
            VALUES(?,(select t2.ID
            from info as t1
            INNER JOIN status_type as t2
            ON t2.ID = t1.status_type
            where t1.status_type = ?),?)                      
            '''    
            args = (ID,status_type,current_date)
                       
   cursor = con.cursor()
   cursor.execute(query,args)
   con.commit()
   st.success('Record added Successfully')`

Comment: Your code will work if there is only one record in info table. written select will output the number of common records of two tables and will cause an error

Comment: Your problem is not the code you wrote. You need to understand the process. When creating a username, by default the status is active. Or create a dropdown in the form to create a new user to choose a status. You should modify the process in your program.

Answer (score 0):

based on the answer of @Mostafa NZ  I modified my query and it becomes like below :

```
query = '''
            INSERT INTO info (ID,name,nickname,mother_name,birthdate,status_type,created_date)
            VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,(select status_type.ID 
                        from status_type
                        where status = ?),?)
                      
            '''    
            args = (ID,name,nickname,mother_name,db,status_type,current_date)
                       
   cursor = con.cursor()
   cursor.execute(query,args)
   con.commit()
   st.success('Record added Successfully')
```

Comment: its better now.